# Alternative strings in output

Tags: python

I have to write a recursive function that takes two strings and give an output of a single string.

```
def alternate("aceg","bdf") -> 'abcedfg'
```

Now the code I have written is

```
def alternate(x, y):
    n = 0  
    while ( n > len("x" or "y"):    
        result = x[n] + y[n]
        n = n + 1    
        return result
```

but it only gives the first two letters `"ab"` I have tried various ways but I can't seem to get the correct answer and on the top of that I also have to use recursion! If anyone could help me with code I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Your code is wrong. it has a syntax error and wont even compile (see condition of `while`). Please correct it and properly indent it.  Also: `"x" or "y" == "x"`.

Comment: I assume the output should be 'abcdefg', not 'abcedfg'?

Comment: Don't deface your questions.

Answer (score 4):

One possibility:

```
def alternate(x, y):
    return x[0] + alternate(y, x[1:]) if x else y
```